# Obter valores de um array separadamente

Tags: php, loop

Tenho uma página no qual me mostra campos de texto a serem preenchidos(inputs), contendo um "+" na mesma, para caso o usuário necessite de mais formulários para preenchimento..

O código do input do formulário que recebe os valores digitado pelo usuário é dessa forma:

```
Nome completo:<input name="nomeCompleto[]" id="nomeCompleto" type="text">
```

Levando em conta que o `"nomeCompleto[]"` é referente a um array, sendo assim, fiz com que meu código PHP recebesse os valores através do `$_POST`, de tal forma:

```
if(isset($_POST['nomeCompleto'])){
foreach($_POST["nomeCompleto"] as $nameC)
    {
        echo " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";

    }
```

Dessa forma o código acima me retorna tais valores:

```
=> João
=> Fernando
=> Jacinto Ades Graça Vindo
=> Lucas
Array ( [0] => João [1] => Fernando [2] => Jacinto Ades Graça Vindo [3] => Lucas )
```

Os valores com `"=>"` são os valores que foram digitados nos inputs pelo usuário, com o php eu fiz que tais valores fossem passados para um array, sendo assim, são ordenados e identificados de tal forma. E com o `"count"` do php, consigo fazer a contagem de quantos itens possui o meu array, sendo assim, ele me imprime na tela o valor `"4"`, por que há 4 valores(partindo do 0 ao 3).

O código por completo que me retorna os valores digitados acima ficou dessa forma:

```
if(isset($_POST['nomeCompleto'])){
foreach($_POST["nomeCompleto"] as $nameC)
    {
        echo " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";

    }
        ?><br /><?php
        print_r(($_POST["nomeCompleto"]));// aqui ele me retorna os valores do array e suas respectivas posições( [0] => João [1] => Fernando...)
        ?><br /><?php

        $count = count($_POST["nomeCompleto"]); // aqui ele realiza a contagem do array via $_POST
        printf($count); // aqui ele me retorna o valor "4" que é a quantidade de 'itens' que compõe meu array.
        ?><br /><?php
        print_r($nameC); /*coloquei esse print_r pra ver o que ele me retornaria apenas com a variável $nameC.. e aqui ele me retorna apenas o ultimo valor do array, que seria "Lucas", cá esta um erro */
        ?><br /><?php

}
```

A primeira questão é:

Em "`echo " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";`" ele me retorna os valores da variável `$nameC` de tal forma:

```
=> João
=> Fernando
=> Jacinto Ades Graça Vindo
=> Lucas
```

Porém, por que quando dou um `"print_r($nameC);"` ele retorna apenas `"Lucas"`? e não todos os outros nomes.. (independe se é `printf` ou `print_r` ou `echo`)

A dúvida é, como posso obter tais valores separadamente dentro de um loop?
Seguindo tal lógica no caso:

```
while($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

printf($nameC[$i]);

}
```

Obs.: a variável `"$nameC"` é a variável que eu instanciei para poder alocar os valores do array(por que no caso o array vem de uma página web, utilizando o `$_POST` eu puxei os valores e atribui tais a essa variável

> Obs.: Necessariamente precisa ser while por que isso rege todo uma
>   repetição de script..

O problema de tal questão é, na lógica do loop que postei, ele me retornaria algo como:

```
1 = L
2 = u
3 = c
4 = a
```

E no caso eu não queria exatamente que ele fizesse a leitura do array dessa forma, por que assim ele ta apenas lendo o ultimo item do array, valor por valor(letra por letra no caso) e me mostrando na tela em suas respectivas posições.

No caso eu queria que fosse imprimido de tal forma:

```
1 = João
2 = Fernando
3 = Jacinto....
4 = Lucas
```

Isso utilizando o loop, qual seria a lógica pra isso ser realizado?

Comment: pode ser feito com um for ao invés de um while?

Comment: Olá Lucas, primeiro bem vindo ao SoPT. Quanto a sua pergunta, sei que tentou representar da melhor forma possível, mas sempre tente postar seu trecho de código que engloba toda a solução para facilitar o entendimento de todos.

Quanto a necessariamente precisar se um `while`, essa estrutura que está utilizando para o `while` é equivalente há um `for` ou `foreach`, nesse caso não faria diferença nenhuma utilizar um ou outro, até pelo contexto um `for` ou `foreach` seria mais adequado.

Comment: Acredito que possa sim, posso tentar alterar o script para se encaixar com o código utilizando o for, qual seria a ideia?

Comment: Tudo bem, vou dar uma editada no tópico em si, acrescentando um pouco mais dos códigos e de detalhes pra que fiquei mais fácil de me ajudar.
Agradecido!

Comment: @Lucas, postei uma resposta, veja se isto te ajuda por favor, caso sim, por favor, marque a pergunta como correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que está abaixo, todas as suas informações serão mostradas da forma correta:

```
<?php
$nomes = Array("João Paulo", "Maria Silva", "José Santos", "Pedro Matoso");
foreach($nomes as $nameC)
    {
        echo " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";

    }
        ?><br /><?php
        print_r($nomes);// Irá mostrar tudo o que estiver dentro do array
        ?><br /><?php

        $count = count($nomes); // Irá realizar a contagem através da variável definida
        printf($count); // Retornará a quantidade de posições do array.
        ?><br /><?php
        print_r(reset($nomes)); /*cAqui irá retornar a primeira posição do array devido ao uso do reset */
        ?><br /><?php
?>
```

A saída deste código será:

```
=> João Paulo
=> Maria Silva
=> José Santos
=> Pedro Matoso

Array ( [0] => João Paulo [1] => Maria Silva [2] => José Santos [3] => Pedro Matoso )
4
João Paulo
```

Veja um [exemplo funcional](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hmyn-hwd2) no phpfiddle.

---

Como falamos nos comentários desta postagem, toda interação com a variável `$nomeC` deverá ser feita dentro do `foreach`, desta forma:

```
<?php
$nomes = Array("João Paulo", "Maria Silva", "José Santos", "Pedro Matoso");
foreach($nomes as $nameC)
    {
        echo " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";
        echo ($nameC . "<br>");
        var_dump($nameC . "<br>");
        echo ("<hr>");

    }
?>
```

Percebi que você está tentando acessar posição de variável for do `foreach`:

```
printf($nameC[1]);
```

Esta variável, após sair dor `foreach` possui apenas uma posição, que seria o último nome da lista de `array` primário.

Caso você queira imprimir um número antes de cada nome, utilize como abaixo:

```
foreach($nomes as $nameC)
{
    echo  $contador . " => " . $nameC . "<BR>";
    echo ($nameC . "<br>");
    var_dump($nameC . "<br>");
    echo ("<hr>");
    $contador++;
}
```

A saída será:

```
1 => João Paulo
João Paulo
string(15) "João Paulo
"
2 => Maria Silva
Maria Silva
string(15) "Maria Silva
"
3 => José Santos
José Santos
string(16) "José Santos
"
4 => Pedro Matoso
Pedro Matoso
string(16) "Pedro Matoso
"
```

Comment: Certo, certo, eu segui essa mesma lógica pro meu código, entretanto, há alguns poréns:
1 - O array é preenchido através dos valores digitados em um input(text) de uma página web.
2 - Após o array ser preenchido, eu faço com que uma variável receba o valor de todos os arrays em sequencia para seguir tal logica do código que você postou, porém ao dar um echo/printf para verificar se a variável ta recebendo todos os valores, ela me imprime apenas o valor do ultimo bloco do array, no seu exemplo, só iria imprimir pra mim "Pedro Matoso" ): e eu não sei o por que

Comment: Sem problemas, neste caso, eu estou definindo valores para ele, mas caso esteja os pegando por `$_POST`, basta continuar fazendo da forma que já está fazendo hoje. Ou poste o código desde quando a variável chega pelo `$_POST` até a hora de fazer o `for` por favor

Comment: Vou terminar de editar o post, de forma mais consistente, com os códigos, a forma como to fazendo a variável receber os valores e etc.. e se puder, você da uma verificada

Comment: ué ): eu fiz exatamente assim, porém ele faz a leitura do ultimo valor do array, como se estivesse sendo feita a contagem das letras, 1 por 1 D:

Comment: @Lucas, eu aguardo a edição completa do seu código para poder te ajudar melhor então

Comment: @Lucas já chegou a validar com um `var_dump` ou semelhante se o seu POST está preenchendo corretamente a variável com todos os dados passados? Difícil ter certeza sem o código, mas acredito que seu array na verdade deve conter somente uma informação. Talvez não seja um problema no `loop`.

Comment: @JaksonFischer prontinho, dei uma editada, acho que dá de entender onde se encontra o erro

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel então, dei uma editada no tópico, deve ser exatamente isso, porém como expliquei lá, dentro do foreach ele me retorna todos os valores do array, porém quando dou um print referente à variável $nameC, ele me retorna só o ultimo valor ):

Comment: @Lucas, editei a resposta, veja como ficou.

Comment: Eu entendi a lógica e me ajudou a retirar umas duvidas, porém o problema agora é só 1. É que como o array é preenchido na página web, eu tenho que puxar os valores de lá via `$_POST` o problema é que pra isso eu preciso usar o foreach, dentro do foreach eu faço os valores serem atribuídos para a variável `"$nameC"` e dou um print, assim, retornando todos os valores do array, até aqui, perfeição! Porém, o problema surge quando eu dou um print FORA DO FOREACH, nesse ponto a variável `$nameC` só me retorna apenas o último valor do array.  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rkrc-12yc nesse sentido

Comment: @Lucas, entenda o seguinte, o código vai fazer todo o `foreach` e somente após a conclusão dele, ele irá interpretar as demais linhas. Como ele contou tudo e número do `count()` foi 4, ele irá definir que a partir deste ponto a variável `$nomeC` passa a receber o valor do último valor do array percorrido, no caso do exemplo o nome **Pedro Matoso**. Isto sempre irá acontecer, devido a ele ter parado nesta posição dentro do `foreach`. Qualquer `echo`, `printf` ou `print_r` que precise fazer, você deverá fazer dentro do próprio for each. Vou colocar uma adição de código no que fiz.

Comment: @Lucas, qual seria a necessidade que você teria de dar um `printf` nos nomes fora do `foreach`? Se conseguir me explicar isto, talvez consiga te ajudar mais

Comment: @JaksonFischer É que no caso isso é um script pra um 'fórum' da empresa, onde o usuário digita na pagina web(nos inputs) a descrição do problema e automaticamente abre um tópico com o que ele digitou, no fórum, utilizando a API do mesmo. Sendo assim eu fiz a ligação da API com o script em PHP, que no caso o que o usuário digita é atribuído à variáveis e essas variáveis se encaixam no código da API. No caso, o script abre várias 'topicos' automaticamente, e eu quero que cada um seja aberto de forma divergente do anterior, no caso se o usuário quiser abrir 3 tópicos com problemas diferentes[+]

Comment: ele só clicaria em um "+", abriria um novo input pra ele na pagina e ele preencheria, dai no caso o array serve pra ordenar as informações que irá para o tópico, sendo assim em um exemplo basico: Usuário digita nos inputs; `|input1: nome: João|` `|input2 nome: Fernando|`, ao clicar em enviar, ele vai abrir dois tópicos, um com o nome "João" e o outro com o nome "Fernando"

Comment: @Lucas, entre nesta [sala](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103095/forum-do-lucas), vamos tentar agilizar o seu problema

Comment: @JaksonFischer certo kkkkkk estou lá, porém não faço ideia aonde se encontra o campo pra mim digitar..

Comment: agora saquei "Você deve ter 20 reputação na The Stack Exchange Network para falar aqui. Veja o FAQ ." ):

Comment: @Lucas, tente novamente, eu dei +1 na sua pergunta para podermos conversar lá

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103098/discussion-between-jakson-fischer-and-lucas).